# how to submit a form using xcode

Tags: html, xcode, forms, webview

I need to automatically push a "submit" button on a webview.
I have:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebResourceLoadDelegate.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *UserNameField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *PasswordField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *IntervalSelector;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *browser;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *IDField;

@end
```

The browser has finished loading, so how do I program an automatic "submit" button push?
I don't know why it won't work, any pointers?

Comment: You would need to redirect to the target url. You can't "automatigically push" a submit button, but you can redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always manipulate the DOM elements to do this kind of things (even submitting a form). Something like:

```
NSString *js = @"document.forms['loginform'].elements['Email'].value='userName@foo.com'";
[[myWebView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:js];
```